# C++ how can I make a swap function between two variables which are different in type

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I want to make swap function, which can take two different type of variables as parameters.
for example)

```
int a = 2;
double b = 1.1
swap(a,b)//wish a = 1.1, b = 2
```

```
    template<typename T, typename U>
    void swap(T& x, U& y)//it doesn't work due to automatic type cast
    {
        U temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
        
       std::cout << "swap" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you expect an `int` to be able to represent 1.1?

Comment: Have you provided overloads for the constructors? (assuming you are talking about UDTs and not ints and floats)

Comment: u can't do that but u can use variants

Comment: I'm studying C++. And I just wondered my question is possible or not...

Comment: `int a = 1.1;` // "a" is truncated to 1

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off studying things about the language that have a practical use?

Comment: @longlive, also you are using `std::endl` wrong https://youtu.be/GMqQOEZYVJQ

Comment: @user1032677, Thank you. I'll check out :)

Comment: @paddy. true but I thought it would be more generic...i was short-sited

Comment: @asmmo I'll look up varints thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that because the objects types can't be changed. the double will be truncated as an int and the integer will be saved as a double. However, you can use `std::variant`s, as follows

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

void swapDoubleVariantByIntOne(std::variant<int, double>& intVar, std::variant<int, double>& doubleVar)
{
    auto temp = std::get<double>(doubleVar);
    doubleVar = std::get<int>(intVar);
    intVar = temp;
    std::cout << "swap" << std::endl;
}
int main(){
    std::variant<int, double> a = 2;
    std::variant<int, double> b = 1.1;
    swapDoubleVariantByIntOne(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << std::get<double>(a)<< " b: " << std::get<int>(b) ;

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5sGohP)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Since the type of `a` is `int`, it cannot hold values like `1.1`. Unlike dynamic typed language like javascript, In static typed language like C++, the type of a variable cannot be changed.